# Construct a sequence in A that converges to the supremum of A

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

It is similar to this question that I learned quite a bit from:

[Showing the set with a $\sup$ has a convergent sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205778/showing-the-set-with-a-sup-has-a-convergent-sequence)

But I want to ask how can I construct an example of (Sn).

i.e.

If A is a nonempty set bounded from above, describe how to create a sequence (Xn) of elements of A which converge to sup(A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at two scenarios. Let $A$ be a non-empty set bounded above. Define $s = \sup A$

If $s\in A$ then the constant sequence where each term is equal to $s$ certainly converges to $s$.

Now onto the other case, where $s \notin A$ and from here I recommend looking at the accepted answer in the link. It explains this case quite well, but if you don't understand, I can try to break it down some.

Because $s$ is the smallest upper bound, we can subtract off $1/n$ from $s$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and in between $s-\frac{1}{n}$ and $s$ there must be some element $x_n \in A$; otherwise $s$ wouldn't be the supremum. Now as $n\to \infty$, we have that $x_n \to s$ as our window from $s-\frac{1}{n}$ to $s$ is shrinking in size and the left side of this window is approaching the right. Therefore the sequence $(x_n)$ will converge to $s$.

---

As an example of the second case, let $A = \{ a\mid 1 \lt a \lt 10 \}$. So $\sup A = 10$. Following our strategy from above, let's first look at the window from $10-\frac11 = 9$ to $10$. Surely we can find $x_1$ in this interval; let's let $x_1 = 9.2$, which indeed is in $A$. Now let's find $x_2$ in the interval of $10-\frac12 = 9.5$ to $10$. Let's choose $x_2 = 9.6$ which again is in $A$.

We can keep this process going on indefinitely and we can certainly create a sequence that will surely converge to $10$

Comment: That was perfect. Thank You!

Comment: Glad to help, and if this helped you feel free to accept this answer, and welcome to math.stackexchange